# Deleting half of dataframe rows which meet condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to extract a subset of a dataframe based on a condition. Let's say

```
 df = pd.Dataframe({'Col1': [values1], 'Col2' = [values2], 'Col3' = [values3]})
```

I'd like to sort by Col2. Of the entries in Col2 that are negative (if any), I'd like to drop the largest half. So if values2 = [-5,10,13,-3,-1,-2], then I'd want to drop the rows corresponding to the values -5 and -3.

If I wanted to simply drop half the entire dataframe after sorting, I (think) could do

```
df = df.iloc[(df.shape[0]/2):]
```

Not sure how to introduce the conditionality of dropping half of only the negative values. The vast majority of my experience is in numpy - still getting used to thinking in terms of dataframes.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight-forward approach, first, you wanted your data-frame sorted:

```
In [16]:  df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': values1, 'Col2':values2, 'Col3': values3})
In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   Col1  Col2 Col3
0     1    -5    a
1     2    10    b
2     3    13    c
3     4    -3    d
4     5    -1    e
5     6    -2    f

In [18]: df.sort_values('Col2', inplace=True)

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
   Col1  Col2 Col3
0     1    -5    a
3     4    -3    d
5     6    -2    f
4     5    -1    e
1     2    10    b
2     3    13    c
```

Then, create a boolean mask for the negative values, use `np.where` to get the indices, cut the indices and half, then drop those indices:

```
In [20]: mask = (df.Col2 < 0)

In [21]: idx, = np.where(mask)

In [22]: df.drop(df.index[idx[:len(idx)//2]])
Out[22]:
   Col1  Col2 Col3
5     6    -2    f
4     5    -1    e
1     2    10    b
2     3    13    c
```

Answer (score 3):

Data input

```
values1 = [-5,10,13,-3,-1,-2]
values2 = [-5,10,13,-3,-1,-2]
values3 = [-5,10,13,-3,-1,-2]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': values1, 'Col2' : values2, 'Col3' : values3})
```

By using `sample` and `concat` , you can calculated the n from sample(n), i simply using 2 here

```
pd.concat([df[df.Col2>0],df[df.Col2<0].sample(2)])
Out[224]: 
   Col1  Col2  Col3
1    10    10    10
2    13    13    13
5    -2    -2    -2
4    -1    -1    -1
```

Comment: So you're concatenating the subset where Col2 has positive values with 2 entries sampled from the subset where Col2 has negative values?  I assume you're using the value 2 because my specific example has 4 negative values & half that is 2?

Comment: Doesn't the .sample(n) method sample randomly from the subset of Col2 < 0?  I get different resulting dataframes on different code runs. I also changed values3 so its elements aren't identical to values1 & values2, and this further confirms my assertion.  Perhaps I'm missing something or interpreting incorrectly?

Comment: @F.F. sample is random pick , if you want just first half you can using index to slice

Comment: I'm constructing several dataframes in a loop. Slicing via index would require me to know where the negative values start (if any even exist for a given df). I'd have to write additional logic to deal with the general case. Either way an interesting solution.  Thank you for the help.