# Drop rows corresponding to groups smaller than specified size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a `DataFrame` of answers for 100 `questions_id` and 50 `user_id`'s.  Each row represents a single question from a specific user.  The table looks something like this.

```
user_id | question_id | timetaken | answer_1 | answer_2 |
1015    | 1           | 30        | A        | C        |
1015    | 2           | 45        | B        | B        |
1016    | 1           | 15        | A        | A        |
1016    | 2           | 55        | A        | D        |
```

I am trying to filter out the users that did not complete the test. My thought process to do this was to count the amount of occurrences each user appears in the table, if the `user_id` 1015 appears in the column `user_id` 100 times, I know they completed the 100 questions.  Unfortunately, I cannot use the `question_id` to filter as the questions are random so the user could answer 5 questions and one of them could have the `question_id = 100`.

I thought this was my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347265/deleting-half-of-dataframe-rows-which-meet-condition) but couldn't work out how to count the occurrences of `user_id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html), very succinct and intended for this purpose.

```
df1 = df.groupby('user_id').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 100)
```

---

For better performance, use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
m = dict(zip(*np.unique(df.user_id, return_counts=True)))
df[df['user_id'].map(m) > 100]
```

Comment: Hi Coldspeed, thanks the groupby and filter worked great for my specific application.  Really appreciate the great community here.  Especially being such a novice.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filter only rows with counts more like `100` times, [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) is for return `Series` with same size like original `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('user_id')['question_id'].transform('size') > 100]
```

**Performance**: Depends of number of rows and length of groups, so best test in real data:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = list('abcde') 
df = pd.DataFrame({'question_id': np.random.choice(L, N, p=(.75,.0001,.0005,.0005,.2489)),
                   'user_id':np.random.randint(10000,size=N)})
df = df.sort_values(['user_id','question_id']).reset_index(drop=True)

In [176]: %timeit df[df.groupby('user_id')['question_id'].transform('size') > 100]
74.8 ms ± 2.69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

#coldspeed solutions
In [177]: %timeit df.groupby('user_id').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 100)
1.4 s ± 44.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [178]: %%timeit
     ...: m = dict(zip(*np.unique(df.user_id, return_counts=True)))
     ...: df[df['user_id'].map(m) > 100]
     ...: 
89.2 ms ± 3.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: jezrael, thank you for your response. In my case coldspeed's solution worked for me.  Im no sure which solution is the better but I understood cold speeds solution a bit easier. I appreciate you taking the time to offer your solution.

Comment: thanks I will spend a bit more time trying to better understand your solution.  I will rather try to use the correct solution. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Steve - hmmm, if check performance paragraph in my answer `filter` is bad choice, because really slow. So dont use it. Better is use his second solution or my solution.

Comment: @Steve If performance is important, I agree. But all solutions are correct, so use whichever you prefer, and whichever is more readable to you in the long run.