# Is there a reason I cannot use the filter function on a pandas Dataframe after using the isin function?

Tags: python, pandas

Could someone help me work out why I cannot use the filter function on a Dataframe that I used the isin function on? I have imported answers.csv into a pandas dataframe. The following code is to remove all answers where 'deleted' is == 1.

```
#remove 'deleted answers' rows from the answers df - cleaning purposes

df_answers_del = df_answers[df_answers['deleted'].isin([0])]
print(df_answers_del)
```

this returns the answers dataframe with all the deleted answers removed from the df.

```
      answer_id  user_id  deleted   ...     comments
0             1     1015        0   ...          NaN
1             2     1019        0   ...          NaN
2             3     1015        0   ...          NaN
3             5     1015        0   ...          NaN
4             6     1099        0   ...          NaN            
5             7     1019        0   ...          NaN
6             9     1099        0   ...          NaN
7            10     1015        0   ...          NaN
```

The idea is to now filter users that have answered all 100 questions by counting the number of occurrences of the user_id in the DF. The code below is cut off at the end, this is a copy of the code.  #df_answers_del.groupby('user_id').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 100)

```
#filter all rows where users have answered all 100 questions
df_answers_del_completed = df_answers_del.groupby('user_id').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 100)
print(df_answers_del_completed)
```

Python does not return any error, just an empty dataframe.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

If I remove the first chunk of code with the isin function, it returns as expected, just included some extra rows with deleted answers and also the incorrect number of completed users as the filter still counts the 'user_id' from the deleted answers.

```
       answer_id  user_id  deleted   ...     comments
0             1     1015        0   ...          NaN
1             2     1019        0   ...          NaN
2             3     1015        0   ...          NaN
3             4     1099        1   ...          NaN
4             5     1015        0   ...          NaN
5             6     1099        0   ...          NaN            
6             7     1019        0   ...          NaN
7             9     1099        0   ...          NaN
8            10     1015        0   ...          NaN
```

I am wanting the results to look something like this.  Assume that the users in the results have answered all 100 questions excluding deleted answers.

```
      answer_id  user_id  deleted   ...     comments
0             1     1015        0   ...          NaN
1             2     1019        0   ...          NaN
2             3     1015        0   ...          NaN
3             5     1015        0   ...          NaN
4             7     1019        0   ...          NaN               
5            10     1015        0   ...          NaN
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `df_answers[df_answers['deleted'] == 0]` would be marginally faster than  `df_answers[df_answers['deleted'].isin([0])]`

Comment: Thanks @JoeHalliwell, I changed my edited my code with what you suggested however it returned with the same empty database.  However when I also applied nixon recommendation by changing the > to ==.  This resolved my problem.  So I used both your solutions together to get a working solution.  Not sure how to mark both answers as accepted.

Comment: @nixon had the right answer -- my suggestion was just a minor optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a reason I cannot use the filter function on a pandas Dataframe after using the isin function?

It depends what you need - if filter lengths from original data (my first solution) or filter from once filtered data like nixon answer or my second solution.

---

I believe you need chain 2 boolean mask in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - first for filter removed rows and second for get all rows with length `100` :

```
mask1 = df_answers['deleted'] == 0
mask2 = df_answers.groupby('user_id')['user_id'].transform('size') == 100

df = df_answers[mask1 & mask2]
```

If performance is important and large data better is avoid `filter` function, because slow, check [timings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53832919/2901002).

So if want filter again:

```
df_answers_del = df_answers[df_answers['deleted'] == 0]
mask = df_answers_del.groupby('user_id')['user_id'].transform('size') == 100
df_answers_del_completed  = df_answers_del[mask]
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael I used your solution as it worked best for me.  All the solutions were helpful and are helping be grasp a better understanding of python.  Thanks everyone for the great community.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see which have answered all 100 questions, why are you using a `>` sign when filtering? Do:

```
df_answers_del_completed = (df_answers_del.groupby('user_id')
                                         .filter(lambda x: len(x) == 100))
```

Comment: Thanks, its so obvious to me now that this is a better option and will use your code as its neater.  However lets assume a user answers 99 questions and has 1 deleted answer.  This would still count that user as completing all 100 questions which would be incorrect.